# A Script To Convert Numbers

Tags: sh

I was hoping someone could assist me in making a linux script that can take a number and convert it to this format.

Here is  a few of examples:

number = 753082360700386  Converted = 7A 35 80 32 06 07 30 68

number = 653082360700387  Converted = 6A 35 80 32 06 07 30 78

number = 453082360700389   Converted = 4A 35 80 32 06 07 30 98

The number will always have one A and last pair of numbers
swapped  from 89 to 98 and next set swapped from 03 to 30 
going from right to left and adding spaces between each pair

Comment: `printf "A%s" 753082360700386 | dd conv=swab 2> /dev/null`

Comment: thanks worked perfectly how would I add space between each pair of numbers?

Comment: I figured it out sed 's/\(.\{2\}\)/\1 /g'